# Do a manual orderby for a queryset in Django

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.11 and I am trying to figure out a way to change the order of a queryset manually.  Here is my setup:

**models.py**

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    channel_no = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.channel_no
```

I have an array of channel numbers that I wish to use for my order:

```
channel_order = ['2','4','6','8','10','1','3','5','7','9']
```

How can I use that order for a queryset?

I know in MySQL you can achieve this by using **field** in a Select statement.  Here is an example:

```
SELECT * FROM Channel
ORDER BY FIELD(`channel_no`,'2','4','6','8','10','1','3','5','7','9')
```

Comment: normally you can use `.order_by('channel_no')`, but this will order lexically for the CharField. Is there a reason why you use a CharField to store numbers instead of an IntegerField?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this.I could make it an IntegerField, however the application is setup where the user enters the channel order they wish to use by entering it as a single string in the database.

Comment: If you explicitly allow strings for ordering, then the lexical ordering is probably what you want. Simply add a `.order_by('channel_no')` to your queryset.

Comment: @RMP please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ordering is odd channel_no after even then I have next solution for you.

```
from django.db.models import Func, F, IntegerField

qs = Channel.objects.annotate(
    channel_no_as_int=Cast(F('channel_no'), IntegerField()),
    ordering=Func(F('channel_no_as_int'), 2, function='Mod') * 5000 + F(
        'channel_no_as_int')).order_by('ordering')
```

As you have max_length = 4 then max channel_no equals to 9999 which means that there could be as max 5000 even and 5000 odd number so I took multiplier=5000 which shifts odd numbers (mod(number, 2) == 1).

UPDATE

As you need custom ordering defined by user this is how you can achieve it:

```
order = '2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '1', '3', '5', '7', '9'
order = map(Value, order)
qs = Channel.objects.annotate(
    ordering=Func('channel_no', *order, function='FIELD')).order_by('ordering')
```